# CakePHP Selecting Nothing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a `Model::find()` call that is generating a SQL warning that I've never seen before. I'm hoping someone else has and can save me some time by pointing me in the right direction. Here's the error:

```
SELECT  FROM `fica_alternative_plans` AS `FicaAlternativePlan`   
 WHERE `FicaAlternativePlan`.`district_id` = '4ec642e2-8270-4b74-b50d-9ca2147402e8'
```

Pretty easy to see the error (no fields in the select list), of course, but I'm wondering how I got into this position. The `Model::find()` call occurs in the `DistrictsController`. As you can see below, there are a number of associated models getting included an only a few (those that are commented out as well as this one) throw this kind of error.

```
$district = $this->District->find(
  'first',
  array(
    'contain'   => array(
      '403bServiceModel' => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      '457bServiceModel' => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      'BusinessOfficer',
      'County',
      'FicaAlternativePlan', //  => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      'PayrollContact',
      'PrimaryContact',
      // 'Section125Plan' => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      // 'SpecialFinalPayPlan' => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      // 'VebWorksitePlan' => array( 'ServiceProvider' => array( 'Address' ) ), 
      'School' => array(
        'order' => array( 'School.name' ),
        'PhysicalAddress'
      ),
      'Superintendent',
      'UnionPresident',
    ),
    'conditions' => array( 'District.id' => $id ),
  )
);
```

The associations are pretty standard, so I'm not sure what kind of condition could cause this sort of thing. Clearly, I've fat-fingered something, but I'm not seeing it right now.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I should add that `District hasOne FicaAlternativePlan` (same for each of the others that throws the warning, but also the same for `403bServiceModel` and `457bServiceModel` which work fine).

Comment: Sorry if this is a naïve question, but what is `contain`? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: have you tried, adding the fields in the options like `'fields'=> array('District.*')` ?? have you tried erasing the cache ?? (sometimes it cache the schema)

Comment: @eaj contain is a [behaviour (containable)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

Comment: @api55 Thanks, I should have recognized that, although I've done little with behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, found it.

The failing models do not extend `AppModel` directly, but have a super class (`Plan`) that extends it. The super class is used for grouping, it would seem, so its `$useTable` is set to false and the failing models were inheriting that value. Other classes extend the same super class, but are each non-standard in some way that required the `$useTable` property to be overridden anyway -- that's why *everything* wasn't failing.

The answer, in case it isn't obvious, is to set the `$useTable` value in order to override the `false` value in the super class.

Thanks for your help, all.